# Mouse coordinates movement from 2d to 3d element javascript

Tags: javascript, 3d, 2d, mouse, coordinate

I'm trying to do dragging of an element which is transformed with 3d css transform, *for example* `rotateX(-50)`

The problem is that I try to drag some element which is nested in transformend element and it inherit his tranformation matrix. In this case the child element has different coordinate system which is 3d to his parent and my mouse move has 2d coordinate system which is different. I did the 2d calculation using the following formula:

```
var x1 = (deltaX * m3d.m11) + (deltaY * m3d.m21) + (0 * m3d.m31) + (1 * m3d.m41);
var y1 = (deltaX * m3d.m12) + (deltaY * m3d.m22) + (0 * m3d.m32) + (1 * m3d.m42);
```

`deltaX` and `deltaY` are the offsets of the mouse movement from the start position of the drag to the current mouse move. `m3d` is an object which contains 4x4 matrix of the current element which is multiplyed with all matrices of his parent elements and in the final is invesed.

I read this in this [site](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/). And this is work for the 2d transformation of the element. When we have transformation of `skew`, `rotateZ`, `scale` there is no problem and the element is moving with mouse cursor. But if we have `rotateX` or `rotateY` the element is flying around the cursor.

I read that we might do raycast of the mouse following this [article](http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html) but I still dont have idea how exactly and what exactly I should do.